# Big image as a thumbnail

Tags: css, overflow, hidden

I'm making thumbnails out of big images and I want thumbnails to have width of 100px and height of 150px how can I hide just the horizontal overflow in the thumbnail?

Comment: `hide just the horizontal overflow in the thumbnail` So you'd want the vertical overflow displayed?

Comment: So that the thumbnail is 100 x 150 and it keeps the original shape, even if it doesn't fit on 100 x 150 frame. For this I need to hide the horizontal part of the picture that won't fit in the frame.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand right, you need to give a overflow:hidden to a div and set a height:100% to the img.

```
.view {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.view img {
    height:100%;
}
```

Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/y0k0ru8h/1/
Is this what you are looking for?